# Is `xargs -t` output stderr or stdout, and can you control it?

Tags: command-line, xargs

say i have a directory with hi.txt and blah.txt and i execute the following command on a linux-ish command line

`ls *.* | xargs -t -i{} echo {}`

the output you will see is

```
echo blah.txt
blah.txt
echo hi.txt
hi.txt
```

i'd like to redirect the stderr output (say 'echo blah.txt' fails...), **leaving only the output from the xargs -t command** written to std out, but it looks as if it's stderr as well.

`ls *.* | xargs -t -i{} echo {} 2> /dev/null`

Is there a way to control it, to make it output to stdout?

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you clarify?  There's 4 outputs: (1) stdout of `echo {}`, (2) stderr of `echo {}`, (3) stdout of xargs, (4) stderr of xargs.  Which of these do you want where?

Comment: stdout of echo {} and any output of xargs -t (which I assume is stderr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I believe what you want is to have as stdout is

- the stdout from the utility that xargs executes
- the listing of commands generated by xargs -t

You want to ignore the stderr stream generated by the 
executed utility.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

First, let's create a better testing utility:

```
% cat myecho
#!/bin/sh
echo STDOUT $@
echo STDERR $@ 1>&2
% chmod +x myecho
% ./myecho hello world
STDOUT hello world
STDERR hello world
% ./myecho hello world >/dev/null
STDERR hello world
% ./myecho hello world 2>/dev/null
STDOUT hello world
%
```

So now we have something that actually outputs to both stdout and stderr, so we
can be sure we're only getting what we want.

A tangential way to do this is not to use xargs, but rather, make.  Echoing a command
and then doing it is kind of what make does.  That's its bag.

```
% cat Makefile
all: $(shell ls *.*)

$(shell ls): .FORCE
  ./myecho $@ 2>/dev/null

.FORCE:
% make
./myecho blah.txt 2>/dev/null
STDOUT blah.txt
./myecho hi.txt 2>/dev/null
STDOUT hi.txt
% make >/dev/null
%
```

If you're tied to using xargs, then you need to modify your utility that
xargs uses so it surpresses stderr.  Then you can use the `2>&1` trick others
have mentioned to move the command listing generated by xargs -t from stderr
to stdout.

```
% cat myecho2
#!/bin/sh
./myecho $@ 2>/dev/null
% chmod +x myecho2
% ./myecho2 hello world
STDOUT hello world
% ls *.* | xargs -t -i{} ./myecho2 {} 2>&1
./myecho blah.txt 2>/dev/null
STDOUT blah.txt
./myecho hi.txt 2>/dev/null
STDOUT hi.txt
% ls *.* | xargs -t -i{} ./myecho2 {} 2>&1 | tee >/dev/null
%
```

So this approach works, and collapses everything you want to stdout (leaving out what you don't want).

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can write a general utility to surpress stderr:

```
% cat surpress_stderr
#!/bin/sh
$@ 2>/dev/null
% ./surpress_stderr ./myecho hello world
STDOUT hello world
% ls *.* | xargs -t -i{} ./surpress_stderr ./myecho {} 2>&1
./surpress_stderr ./myecho blah.txt 2>/dev/null
STDOUT blah.txt
./surpress_stderr ./myecho hi.txt 2>/dev/null
STDOUT hi.txt
%
```

Comment: i was kinda hoping for a xargs -err=stdout -t, but if xargs doesn't have that option, piping to a script rather than the actual command would work. thx

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
ls | xargs -t -i{} echo {} 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

The `2>&1` sends the standard error from `xargs` to where standard output is currently going; the `>/dev/null` sends the original standard output to `/dev/null`.  So, the net result is that standard output contains the echo commands, and `/dev/null` contains the file names.  We can debate about spaces in file names and whether it would be easier to use a `sed` script to put 'echo' at the front of each line (with no `-t` option), or whether you could use:

```
ls | xargs -i{} echo echo {}
```

(Tested: Solaris 10, Korn Shell ; should work on other shells and Unix platforms.)

---

If you don't mind seeing the inner workings of the commands, I did manage to segregate the error output from `xargs` and the error output of the command executed.

```
al * zzz | xargs -t 2>/tmp/xargs.stderr -i{} ksh -c "ls -dl {} 2>&1"
```

The (non-standard) command `al` lists its arguments one per line:

```
for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done
```

The first redirection (`2>/tmp/xargs.stderr`) sends the error output from `xargs` to the file `/tmp/xargs.stderr`.  The command executed is '`ksh -c "ls -dl {} 2>&1"`', which uses the Korn shell to run `ls -ld` on the file name with any error output going to standard output.

The output in `/tmp/xargs.stderr` looks like:

```
ksh -c ls -dl x1 2>&1
ksh -c ls -dl x2 2>&1
ksh -c ls -dl xxx 2>&1
ksh -c ls -dl zzz 2>&1
```

I used '`ls -ld`' in place of `echo` to ensure I was testing errors - the files `x1`, `x2`, and `xxx` existed, but `zzz` does not.

The output on standard output looked like:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler rd          1020 May  9 13:05 x1
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler rd          1069 May  9 13:07 x2
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler rd            87 May  9 20:42 xxx
zzz: No such file or directory
```

When run without the command wrapped in '`ksh -c "..."`', the I/O redirection was passed as an argument to the command ('`ls -ld`'), and it therefore reported that it could not find the file '`2>&1`'.  That is, `xargs` did not itself use the shell to do the I/O redirection.

It would be possible to arrange for various other redirections, but the basic problem is that `xargs` makes no provision for separating its own error output from that of the commands it executes, so it is hard to do.

The other rather obvious option is to use `xargs` to write a shell script, and then have the shell execute it.  This is the option I showed before:

```
ls | xargs -i{} echo echo {} >/tmp/new.script
```

You can then see the commands with:

```
cat /tmp/new.script
```

You can run the commands to discard the errors with:

```
sh /tmp/new.script 2>/dev/null
```

And, if you don't want to see the standard output from the commands either, append `1>&2` to the end of the command.

Comment: wouldn't this redirect all errors? I just want to capture the output from xargs, not all stderr :(

Comment: There isn't a meaningful distinction - there's standard error from xargs and what it runs, so it will indeed redirect 'all errors'.  You can write your own xargs if you want it to do something else.  As shown, the 'echo' command won't send anything to stderr anyway, so I'm not clear what the issue is -- you probably have simplified the question using echo.

Comment: thanks for the insite and info how to use make...  i think in the end it's just easier to write a mini bash shell and have xargs pipe into that.  thanks for the writeup tho

Answer (score 1):

It looks like xargs -t goes to stderr, and there's not much you can do about it.

You could do:

`ls | xargs -t -i{} echo "Foo: {}" >stderr.txt | tee stderr.txt`

to display only the stderr data on your terminal as your command runs, and then grep through stderr.txt after to see if anything unexpected occurred, along the lines of `grep -v Foo: stderr.txt`

Also note that on Unix, `ls *.*` isn't how you display everything.  If you want to see all the files, just run `ls` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs -t` echos the commands to be executed to stderr before executing them.  If you want them to instead echo to stderr, you can pipe stderr to stdout with the `2>&1` construct:

```
ls *.* | xargs -t -i{} echo {} 2>&1
```

Comment: I think u mean stdout the 2nd time you mentioned it, and this runs into the same issue as i only want stderr msg's from xargs, not all stderr messages.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem using GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ would do the right thing:

```
ls *.* | parallel -v echo {} 2> /dev/null
```